# How do I create multiple move output

Tags: engines

I have an old Chessbase Light with Fritz 4. Fritz displays the best 5 moves. Is there any way to make Arena 3.5 display the 5 best moves, instead of the single move output. Thanks.

Comment: Start playing with `fen` and `pgn`, so you get 360° notion around draughts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Chessbase 2009 software, which is what I think you're showing, but your answer did inspire me to look deeper into the issue.

I did find that with Arena 3.5:

1) right click with the mouse in the engine analysis box area.
2) left click the first option, Configure Rybka (or whatever engine you are using).
3) set MultiPV to 5.